# Weird issue with String

Tags: java, string, oop

I am working on a multiplayer game.. and i came up with a really weird situation.
It's even possible? -

```
System.out.println(foo);                    // left
System.out.println(foo instanceof String)  // true
System.out.println(foo == "left")         // false
```

I don't understand how it's even possible..

I really don't think it will be a good idea to post all of my code.
Any ideas why its like that? and how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible?

Comment: Is `foo` String instance?

Comment: @JakubHr Yes.. as you can see in the second line of code.

Comment: might be the popular question is so . __asked many times__

Comment: @sankrish i couldn't find an answer for it.. i googled and i couldn't find. lol i am sorry that its a duplicate :(

Comment: When you use `==` on *references* you are comparing two *references* to see if they point to the same object.  `==` doesn't compare the contents of those objects.

Comment: search on so before you post it .see [ask]

Comment: You need to know how to compare `String`s in `Java`. Check this thread: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't compare Strings by == operator, use equals method instead.